# Laravel Spatie 403 User is not logged in

Tags: laravel, laravel-permission

I am using multi auth following this tutorial: https://github.com/sujalpatel2209/LaravelMultiUserAuthentication
and I am trying to implement spatie following this tutorial: https://www.itsolutionstuff.com/post/laravel-58-user-roles-and-permissions-tutorialexample.html
But the problem is, I can't access 'Role Management' page. It say's 403
User is not logged in.
I am trying to follow this instruction too, but still stuck
https://docs.spatie.be/laravel-permission/v3/basic-usage/multiple-guards/

can you solve this problem please?

**Admin**

```
class Admin extends Authenticatable {
    use Notifiable, HasRoles;
    use SoftDeletes;

    protected $guard_name = 'admin';
}
```

**Web.php**

```
Route::group(['middleware' => 'checkAdminLogin'], function() {
 //Manage Roles
    Route::resource('roles','RoleController');
});
```

**CreateAdminUserSeeder.php**

```
class CreateAdminUserSeeder extends Seeder
{
    /**
    * Run the database seeds.
    *
    * @return void
    */
    public function run()
    {
        $user = Admin::create([
            'id' => '7',
            'name' => 'Hardik Savani', 
            'email' => 'admin@gmail.com',
            'password' => bcrypt('123456'),
            'created_by' => '0',
            'created_at' => '2020-04-29 12:43:27',
            'updated_at' => '2020-04-29 12:43:27',
            'username' => 'hardik',
            'roles' => '["ADMIN"]',
            'avatar' => '',
            'status' => 'ACTIVE'
        ]);

        $role = Role::create(['guard_name' => 'admin', 'name' => 'Admin']);
        $permissions = Permission::pluck('id','id')->all();
        $role->syncPermissions($permissions);   
        $user->assignRole([$role->id]);
    }
}
```

**Auth.php**

```
'guards' => [
        'admin' => [
            'driver' => 'session',
            'provider' => 'admin'
        ],

        'student' => [
            'driver' => 'session',
            'provider' => 'student'
        ],

        'web' => [
            'driver' => 'session',
            'provider' => 'users',
        ],

        'api' => [
            'driver' => 'token',
            'provider' => 'users',
        ],
    ],
'providers' => [
        'admin' => [
            'driver' => 'eloquent',
            'model' => App\Admin::class
        ],

        'student' => [
            'driver' => 'eloquent',
            'model' => App\Student::class
        ],

        'users' => [
            'driver' => 'eloquent',
            'model' => App\User::class,
        ],

        // 'users' => [
        //     'driver' => 'database',
        //     'table' => 'users',
        // ],
    ],
```

**RoleController.php**

```
class RoleController extends Controller
{
    /**
    * Display a listing of the resource.
    *
    * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
    */
    function __construct() {
        $this->middleware('permission:role-list|role-create|role-edit|role-delete', ['only' => ['index','store']]);
        $this->middleware('permission:role-create', ['only' => ['create','store']]);
        $this->middleware('permission:role-edit', ['only' => ['edit','update']]);
        $this->middleware('permission:role-delete', ['only' => ['destroy']]);
    }

    /**
    * Display a listing of the resource.
    *
    * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
    */
    public function index(Request $request) {
        $roles = Role::orderBy('id','DESC')->paginate(5);
        return view('roles.index',compact('roles'))->with('i', ($request->input('page', 1) - 1) * 5);
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi, you are likely to get a better response if you explain what you have already tried and post an example of the code you have written. Stackoverflow is a community here to help, but we aren't freelancers to write your code for you ;)

Comment: @Spholt: I've updated the answer. Please check!

Answer (score 3):

You can pass you guard name as well

```
$this->middleware('permission:role-list|role-delete,**YOURGUARDNAME**', ['only' => ['index','store']]);
```